# fail2ban apache repeated 401 requests

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I would like to fail2ban repeated 401 errors to my site

My log file entry...

```
116.108.172.173 - - [28/Aug/2018:08:30:36 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 742
```

My Attempt at fail2ban conf

```
 [Definition]
 failregex = (?P<host>[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}) . . .+ .+ .+ .+ .+ 401 [0-9]+
```

It doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

Comment: In your definition you'll need a `datepattern` to patch the date portion of your line. Then with your `failregex` you'll need `<HOST>` as the generic IP match and the rest of the regex to match the line (I think with the datepattern removed). Read through the [FILTERS](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/FILTERS) documentation and use the `fail2ban-regex [-D]` to help matching.

Comment: [suggested starting point](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/config/filter.d/nginx-botsearch.conf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your regex simple.

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> .+\" 401 \d+ .*$
```

should do the job

Comment: I implemented this simpler regex, and tested with the fail2ban-regex on some old files. It does the job! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Fedora 27 / CentOS / RHEL

etc > fail2ban > filter.d > some-new-filter.conf

:: examples for filtering out .*cgi* and 404 requests, whilst preventing anything but the actual domain

:: referer:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.*(\.cgi\?).*$
            ^<HOST>.+\/.+\/.+\/.*\"\s(404)\s.*$
            ^<HOST>.+\/.+\/.+\/.*(\"http:\/\/some\.info\/.+\")\s.*$
```

then: etc > fail2ban > jail.conf

```
[some-new-filter]
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
           %(apache_error_log)s
maxretry = 2
```

Test with:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/httpd/error_log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/some-new-filter.conf
fail2ban-regex /var/log/httpd/access_log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/some-new-filter.conf
```

Restart fail2ban

Comment: Maaaan! Great mentioning how to test a regex filter! Thank you very much indeed!